# Multiple Functions for probability

Tags: functions, maxima-software

$$Pr(V1) =p + p \times Pr(V3)$$

$$Pr(V2) =p \times Pr(V1)$$

$$Pr(V4) =p \times Pr(V2)$$

$$Pr(V3) =q + q \times Pr(V3) + q \times Pr(V1) +q \times Pr(V2)$$

How would I solve for $Pr(V4)$ in maxima or by hand?